# Does atmospheric pressure determine gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, vacuum, atmospheric-science

If all the air were removed from a room creating a vacuum, would an object be weightless?

Comment: No, not at all. See e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVpXrbZ4bnU).

Comment: There is a misconception that there is no gravity in outer space (a vacuum) because astronauts are seen floating around in the space station.  This occurs not because there is not gravity, but because the astronauts are actually in free fall around the earth.  Objects in free fall ALWAYS look like they are weightless (aka in the absence of gravity).

Comment: Presence of air, here on the Earth, affects weight the other way around: due to Archimede's principle, objects weight slightly less than without air. Gravity does not depend on the presence of air.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't. Atmospheric pressure does not create gravity.

Answer (score 1):

No, atmospheric pressure does not produce gravity. For example, there is gravity on the Moon, even though the Moon has no atmosphere at all.

However, gravity does produce atmospheric pressure. What we call atmospheric pressure is the weight of all Earth's air pushing down on us due to gravity. Atmospheric pressure at sea level is about 15 pounds per square inch. So if you took all the air in a giant, tall, one-square-inch column from sea level all the way up to the top of the atmosphere (about 100 miles), that air would weight about 15 pounds.

Answer (score 1):

No, atmospheric pressure does not determine gravity. Gravity is defined as directly proportional to the product of the masses of two objects and inversely proportional to the square of their separation.

Therefore, both the gravitational force and the gravitational field strength can only be affected by mass and distance of separation.

Answer (score 0):

Air pressure has no effect on gravity, which accelerates all objects equally. However, air friction slows down lighter objects so they seem to fall slower. Air in a room would in fact make objects weigh slightly less, as the air has a buoyant effect, similar to what happens in water.

There have been many experiments to show that gravity works just the same, regardless of the presence of an atmosphere. Note that in these experiments both objects fall at the same rate. The absence of air does not make either the hammer or the feather float, so gravity is still just as effective.

I have seen a few experiments that show the effects of the atmosphere on TV. One is the [Mythbusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eTw35ZD1Ig). They dropped a hammer and a feather in a small NASA vacuum chamber, showing quite clearly that they fall at the same rate in vacuum.

Another one, [much more spectacular](https://www.siliconrepublic.com/innovation/brian-coxs-galileo-experiment-is-mind-blowing-video), was by [Dr Brian Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Cox_(physicist)) who uses a huge NASA vacuum chamber. That was part of his TV series, "[The Human Universe](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0276q28)"

**EDIT**

How could I forget that David Scott did the [same experiment on the moon!](https://moon.nasa.gov/resources/331/the-apollo-15-hammer-feather-drop/)